# Preventing errors with HTMLAgilitypack in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, parsing, error-handling, html-parsing, html-agility-pack

I'm using the HTMLAgilityPack to parse HTML pages. However at some point I try to parse wrong data (in this specific case an image), which ofc fails for obvious reasons.

```
Private Sub parseHtml(ByVal content As String, ByVal url As String)
    Try
        Dim contentHash As String = hashGenerator.ComputeHash(content, "SHA1")
        Dim doc As HtmlDocument = New HtmlDocument()

        doc.Load(New StringReader(content))

        Dim root As HtmlNode = doc.DocumentNode
        Dim anchorTags As New List(Of String)

        For Each link As HtmlNode In root.SelectNodes("//a")
            cururl = link.OuterHtml
            If link.Attributes("href") Is Nothing Then Continue For
            If Uri.IsWellFormedUriString(link.Attributes("href").Value, UriKind.Absolute) Then
                urlQueue.Enqueue(link.Attributes("href").Value)
            Else
                Dim myUri As New Uri(url)
                urlQueue.Enqueue(myUri.Scheme & "://" & myUri.Host & link.Attributes("href").Value)
            End If
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Error (parseHtml(" & url & "))")
    End Try
End Sub
```

The error I get is:

> A first chance exception of type
>   'System.NullReferenceException'
>   occurred in Webcrawler.exe Object
>   reference not set to an instance of an
>   object.

On the content I try to parse:

> �����Iޥ�+�: 8�0�x�

How to check whether the content is 'parse-able' before trying to parse it to prevent the error?

For now it is an image which makes an error popup however I think it might be just anything which isn't (x)html.

Thanks in advance ow great community :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check the returned `content-type` header before trying to parse the returned data.

For an HTML page this should be `text/html`, for XHTML is would be `application/xhtml+xml`.

Comment: Wow. This is just great. I haven't tested it yet, but I think you just answered this question and another question I didn't even ask! I was wondering how to check for the response type and content-type of my Webrequest and I think you just pointed me in that direction. Going to test it now!

Answer (score 0):

If you only have the content (If you can't have access to original HTTP headers like Oded suggested), you could assume a good HTML string should contain at least a "<" character within, say, the 10 first characters of the string.

Of course, there is no guarantee and you will still need to handle the extreme cases, but this should discard most garbage or unexpected content types, and will let specific encoding bytes pass fine (like UTF-8 byte order mark, etc...).